# MATLAB Keyboard inputs not updating on "Pong" game

Tags: matlab, pong

I am trying to re-create "Pong" in MATLAB, and so far I have been able to generate the figure, draw a court, draw the paddles, and draw the ball. At this point, I am trying to update the position of the paddles (move them up and down) via keyboard input. I am attempting to utilize MATLAB's built-in "KeyPressFcn" and "KeyReleaseFcn" features in order to do this, but for some reason the paddles still aren't moving. My code is below. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
% Create court figure, make title, set axis, draw middle dotted line and
% top/bottom lines, turn axis off
court = figure;
set(court, 'Color', 'black', 'toolbar', 'none', 'menubar', 'none');
title('ENGR 122 PONG', 'FontSize', 18, 'Color', 'w');
axis([0 14 0 12]);
line([7 7],[0 12],'LineStyle',':','LineWidth',1,'Color','yellow');
line([0 14], [12 12], 'LineStyle', '-', 'LineWidth', 3, 'Color', 'yellow');
line([0 14], [0 0], 'LineStyle', '-', 'LineWidth', 3, 'Color', 'yellow');
axis off

% Initialize inputs for left and right paddle
left_input = 0;
right_input = 0;

% Initialize ball on court
hold on
ball = plot(7, 6, 'w.', 'MarkerSize', 15);

% Initialize paddles on court, set speed
left_bottom = 5;
left_height = 2;
right_bottom = 5;
right_height = 2;
left_paddle = line([1 1], [left_bottom (left_bottom + left_height)], 'LineWidth', 5, 'Color', 'red');
right_paddle = line([13 13], [right_bottom (right_bottom + right_height)], 'LineWidth', 5, 'Color', 'blue');

% Initialize score on screen
left_score = 0;
right_score = 0;
draw_left_score = text(2, 10, num2str(left_score), 'FontSize', 25, 'Color', 'yellow');
draw_right_score = text(12, 10, num2str(right_score), 'FontSize', 25, 'Color', 'yellow');

% While neither player has scored 10 points yet
while (left_score < 10 || right_score < 10)
    % Update left and right paddle values
    left_bottom = updateLeft(left_input, left_bottom)
    right_bottom = updateRight(right_input, right_bottom);

    % Set Key listeners to figure
    set(court, 'KeyPressFcn', @keyDown, 'KeyReleaseFcn', @keyUp);

    % Update left and right paddle positions on figure
    set(left_paddle, 'YData', [left_bottom (left_bottom + left_height)]);
    set(right_paddle, 'YData', [right_bottom (right_bottom + right_height)]);

end

% Function listening for keys being pressed
function keyDown(source, event)
    if event.Key == 'q'
        left_input = 1;
    end
    if event.Key == 'a'
        left_input = -1;
    end
    if event.Key == 'o'
        right_input = 1;
    end
    if event.Key == 'l'
        right_input = -1;
    end
end

% Function listening for keys being released
function keyUp(source, event)
    if event.Key == 'q'
        left_input = 0;
    end
    if event.Key == 'a'
        left_input = 0;
    end
    if event.Key == 'o'
        right_input = 0;
    end
    if event.Key == 'l'
        right_input = 0;
    end   
end

% Function updating left paddle
function left_bottom = updateLeft(left_input, left_bottom)
    if left_input == 1
        left_bottom = left_bottom + .05;
    elseif left_input == -1
        left_bottom = left_bottom - .05;
    end
end

% Function updating right paddle
function right_bottom = updateRight(right_input, right_bottom)
    if right_input == 1
        right_bottom = right_bottom + .05;
    elseif right_input == -1
        right_bottom = right_bottom - .05;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a simple solution to the problem.

Call `drawnow` function at the end of the while loop.
You can also add pause command like `pause(0.01)`.

```
% While neither player has scored 10 points yet
while (left_score < 10 || right_score < 10)
    % Update left and right paddle values
    left_bottom = updateLeft(left_input, left_bottom);
    right_bottom = updateRight(right_input, right_bottom);

    % Set Key listeners to figure
    set(court, 'KeyPressFcn', @keyDown, 'KeyReleaseFcn', @keyUp);

    % Update left and right paddle positions on figure
    set(left_paddle, 'YData', [left_bottom (left_bottom + left_height)]);
    set(right_paddle, 'YData', [right_bottom (right_bottom + right_height)]);

    drawnow
end
```

The problem is that Matlab blocks all events when tight loop is executed.
Adding `drawnow` or `pause`, enables Matlab respond to the event.

---

The problem might also be related to variables **Scope Rules**.
Make sure the `end` statement of the main function, is at the last code line of the file.

Check the following (complete code):

```
function PongGame()
court = figure;
set(court, 'Color', 'black', 'toolbar', 'none', 'menubar', 'none');
title('ENGR 122 PONG', 'FontSize', 18, 'Color', 'w');
axis([0 14 0 12]);
line([7 7],[0 12],'LineStyle',':','LineWidth',1,'Color','yellow');
line([0 14], [12 12], 'LineStyle', '-', 'LineWidth', 3, 'Color', 'yellow');
line([0 14], [0 0], 'LineStyle', '-', 'LineWidth', 3, 'Color', 'yellow');
axis off

% Initialize inputs for left and right paddle
left_input = 0;
right_input = 0;

% Initialize ball on court
hold on
ball = plot(7, 6, 'w.', 'MarkerSize', 15);

% Initialize paddles on court, set speed
left_bottom = 5;
left_height = 2;
right_bottom = 5;
right_height = 2;
left_paddle = line([1 1], [left_bottom (left_bottom + left_height)], 'LineWidth', 5, 'Color', 'red');
right_paddle = line([13 13], [right_bottom (right_bottom + right_height)], 'LineWidth', 5, 'Color', 'blue');

% Initialize score on screen
left_score = 0;
right_score = 0;
draw_left_score = text(2, 10, num2str(left_score), 'FontSize', 25, 'Color', 'yellow');
draw_right_score = text(12, 10, num2str(right_score), 'FontSize', 25, 'Color', 'yellow');

% While neither player has scored 10 points yet
while (left_score < 10 || right_score < 10)
    % Update left and right paddle values
    left_bottom = updateLeft(left_input, left_bottom);
    right_bottom = updateRight(right_input, right_bottom);

    % Set Key listeners to figure
    set(court, 'KeyPressFcn', @keyDown, 'KeyReleaseFcn', @keyUp);

    % Update left and right paddle positions on figure
    set(left_paddle, 'YData', [left_bottom (left_bottom + left_height)]);
    set(right_paddle, 'YData', [right_bottom (right_bottom + right_height)]);

    drawnow
end

% Function listening for keys being pressed
function keyDown(source, event)
    if event.Key == 'q'
        left_input = 1;
    end
    if event.Key == 'a'
        left_input = -1;
    end
    if event.Key == 'o'
        right_input = 1;
    end
    if event.Key == 'l'
        right_input = -1;
    end
end

% Function listening for keys being released
function keyUp(source, event)
    if event.Key == 'q'
        left_input = 0;
    end
    if event.Key == 'a'
        left_input = 0;
    end
    if event.Key == 'o'
        right_input = 0;
    end
    if event.Key == 'l'
        right_input = 0;
    end   
end

% Function updating left paddle
function left_bottom = updateLeft(left_input, left_bottom)
    if left_input == 1
        left_bottom = left_bottom + .05;
    elseif left_input == -1
        left_bottom = left_bottom - .05;
    end
end

% Function updating right paddle
function right_bottom = updateRight(right_input, right_bottom)
    if right_input == 1
        right_bottom = right_bottom + .05;
    elseif right_input == -1
        right_bottom = right_bottom - .05;
    end
end

end
```

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it didn't work. The problem that I am having is that "left_bottom" and "right_bottom" are not getting incremented like they should be. When I press the appropriate keys, those values should be getting changed by 0.05, and this will allow the paddles to move up and down at that increment. I even left the ";" out after each one in the while loop to see if the value changes (they are initialized at 5), and they aren't, but I don't see where the disconnect is between the key listeners and the update of those variables in the while loop.

Comment: Copy and paste the complete code... When I press 'q' key, the red paddle moves up.

Comment: Thanks! So the main changes you made were to add the pause, but also you wrapped the entire program by the function called PongGame. How come that makes it work properly?

Comment: Scope Rules: By default variable like `left_input` is visible only by the function `keyUp`. `left_input` inside `keyUp` and outside `keyUp` are different variables with the same name. Wrapping the program by the function, make the variables kind of `Global` in the wrapped function.